# unable to place textinput at the end of the text (i.e at end of last word of text) in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

The requirement is I need a textinput beside the text(multiline text). Normally what I did is , I have taken the width of the text and adjusted the x and y position of the textinput, so that it will be placed just beside the text

EX: `sample text aaaaa <TextInput>`.
But if the text is in multiple lines, then that the textinput should be placed at the end of the text, not just beside text.

EX: 
`sample textaaaaaaaaaaaaa
aaaa bbb <textinput>`

But The output I am getting is as below

`sample textaaaaaaaaaaaaa <textinput>
aaaa bbb`

Do anyone have any suggestion.

Below is the code
`MemoStepLabelBox.as`

```
package {
import mx.controls.Label;
import mx.controls.Text;
import mx.controls.TextInput;
import mx.core.Container;

public class MemoStepLabelBox extends Container
{
    public function MemoStepLabelBox()
    {
        super();
    }

    public var textLabel:Text;

    public var input:TextInput;


    override protected function createChildren():void
    {
        super.createChildren();
        addChild(textLabel);
        if (spacer)
        {
            addChild(spacer);
        }
        if (input)
        {
            addChild(input);

        }

    }


    override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

        var labelWidth:Number = textLabel.getExplicitOrMeasuredWidth();
        var requiredWidth:Number = labelWidth;

        if (input)
        {
            input.setActualSize(input.getExplicitOrMeasuredWidth(), input.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight());
            requiredWidth += input.width;
        }

        if (unscaledWidth)
        {

            textLabel.setActualSize(labelWidth, textLabel.getExplicitOrMeasuredHeight());
            textLabel.move(0, (unscaledHeight - textLabel.height) / 2);
            currentX = textLabel.x + textLabel.width;


            if (input)
            {
            input.move(currentX, (unscaledHeight - input.height) / 2);
            currentX = input.x + input.width;
            }


        }
    }
}
}
```

`main.mxml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:local="*"  creationComplete="stack.selectedIndex = 0;">
      <mx:Button label="Insert Steps" width="100" click="onInsertStepsClick()"/>-->

    <local:MemoStepLabelBox id="hbxHasInput" width="100%">
        <local:textLabel>
            <mx:Text id="txtStep" width="100%"
                     text="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa aaaa"  />
        </local:textLabel>
        <local:spacer>
            <mx:Spacer id="hasInputSpacer" width="6" themeColor="green" />
        </local:spacer>
        <local:input>
            <mx:TextInput id="txtIn" width="100" paddingTop="0"
                          paddingBottom="0"     />
        </local:input>

    </local:MemoStepLabelBox>


</mx:Application>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do.  Could you rephrase your question (and cut down the big code dump to a small example showing only relevant code)?  Also, you say you're "unable to add textinput" ...do you get a compiler error?  Does the code compile, but you get a runtime error?  Or does it simply run without doing what you expect?

Comment: Hello @Brian , updated the question, please have a look